# RuntimeError (You want to finish 2 frames, but stack size is only <number> in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I am using rails_admin gem and I am getting the below error.

> RuntimeError (You want to finish 2 frames, but stack size is only
>   -97):   lib/rails_admin/recalculate_charges.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> RuntimeError (You want to finish 2 frames, but stack size is only
>   -97):   lib/rails_admin/recalculate_charges.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> Rendered
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@commeasure_reports/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb
>   (85.2ms)   Rendered
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@commeasure_reports/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb
>   (85.2ms)   Rendered
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@commeasure_reports/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (2.0ms)   Rendered
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@commeasure_reports/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (2.0ms)   Rendered
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@commeasure_reports/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
>   (2.0ms)   Rendered
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@commeasure_reports/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
>   (2.0ms)   Rendered
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@commeasure_reports/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb
>   (103.3ms)   Rendered
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@commeasure_reports/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb
>   (103.3ms)

I am calling an ajax call, which collects some ids and pass it to the custom action

```
$(".recalculate-bulk-charges").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var booking_report_ids = []
      $(".booking_report_row input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
        if (parseInt($(this).val()) != NaN) {
          booking_report_ids.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
        }
      });
      $.get("url", {"br_ids[]": booking_report_ids}).done(function(){
        window.location = "url";
      })
    })
```

When I restart my server, the error doesn't appear again. Please help me for the same.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: I have updated the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the byebug into the custom action. It was giving the error due to byebug

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to have been fixed by the latest byebug for ruby 2.1.5 or higher: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/127.  Try upgrading byebug and ruby.